# ¿COMO CREAR UN ARCHIVO DE TEXTO UTILIZANDO EL PATRON MVC?

Tags: java, mvc, jsp

Necesito ayuda con este problema, ya lo he realizado con exito anteriormente, pero ahora lo utilizo con servidores y me da error.

Estoy recibiendo el tipico NullPointerException que es igual a algun objeto vacio, pero no tengo ni idea donde esta el error.

Mi formulario JSP es el siguiente el cual envia los datos a mi controlador(SERVLET).

```
 <form action="ControladorArchivos" method="get">

  <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="creacionArchivo">

   Especifique Ruta <input type="text" name="crearRuta"><br><br>

   Especifique Nombre <input type="text" name="crearNombre"><br><br>

   Especifique Texto <input type="text" name="crearTexto"><br><br>

   <input style="background-color: white; color: black; font-family: 
   verdana; font-size:25px;" 

 type="submit" value="Crear Archivo">
```

mi metodo doGet que me permite redirigir mi user a conveniencia

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

    EstadoAccion = request.getParameter("accion");

    if(EstadoAccion == null) EstadoAccion = "Nulo";

    switch(EstadoAccion) {

    case "Nulo":

        System.out.println("Archivo Nulo!");

        break;


    case "creacionArchivo":

        try {

            CreameArchivo(request, response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            System.out.println("Error Especifico: " + e.getMessage());

            System.out.println("Error al intentar crear el archivo!");

            e.printStackTrace();




        }

        break;

    }
}
```

Mi servlet es este que recibe los datos de mi vista(JSP) Y LOS envia los Datos a mi modelo.

```
protected void CreameArchivo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

    EstadoRuta = request.getParameter("crearRuta");

    EstadoNombre = request.getParameter("crearNombre");

    EstadoTexto = request.getParameter("crearTexto");

    objetoArchivo = new ObjetoArchivos(EstadoRuta, EstadoNombre, EstadoTexto);

    System.out.println(objetoArchivo.getUnionRyN());

    modeloArchivo.CreaArchivo(objetoArchivo);

    ListaArchivo = new ArrayList<String>();

    ListaArchivo.add(objetoArchivo.EstadoArchivo);

    request.setAttribute("miEstado", ListaArchivo);

    reenvio = request.getRequestDispatcher("ArchivosBienvenida.jsp");

    reenvio.forward(request, response);





}
```

Mi clase Modelo es esta que se encarga de crear mi archivo

package Archivos;

import java.io.*;

public class ModeloArchivos {

```
private File fila;

private FileWriter escribirArchivo;

private FileReader leerArchivo;

private BufferedReader miBufer;

private String ConsigueRuta;

public ModeloArchivos() {


}

public String CreaArchivo(ObjetoArchivos objetoArchivo) throws Exception{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        fila = new File(objetoArchivo.getUnionRyN());

        ConsigueRuta = fila.getAbsolutePath();

        fila.createNewFile();

        escribirArchivo = new FileWriter(ConsigueRuta);

        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

            escribirArchivo.write(objetoArchivo.getMiTexto());
        }

        escribirArchivo.close();

        if(fila.exists()) {

            objetoArchivo.setEstadoArchivo("Archivo creado correctamente!");

            //System.out.println(EstadoArchivo);
        }

        else {

            objetoArchivo.setEstadoArchivo("Error al intentar crear el archivo!");

            //System.out.println(EstadoArchivo);
        }


    return objetoArchivo.getEstadoArchivo();


}
```

}

y mi clase objeto\pojo con las Declaraciones basicas

public class ObjetoArchivos {

```
public String unionRyN, miRuta, miNombre, miTexto, EstadoArchivo;

public ObjetoArchivos(String miRuta , String miNombre, String miTexto) {

    super();

    this.miRuta = miRuta;

    this.miNombre = miNombre;

    this.miTexto = miTexto;

    this.unionRyN = this.miRuta + this.miNombre;
}

public String getMiRuta() {
    return miRuta;
}

public void setMiRuta(String miRuta) {
    this.miRuta = miRuta;
}

public String getMiNombre() {
    return miNombre;
}

public void setMiNombre(String miNombre) {
    this.miNombre = miNombre;
}

public String getMiTexto() {
    return miTexto;
}

public void setMiTexto(String miTexto) {
    this.miTexto = miTexto;
}


public String getEstadoArchivo() {
    return EstadoArchivo;
}

public void setEstadoArchivo(String estadoArchivo) {
    EstadoArchivo = estadoArchivo;
}



public String getUnionRyN() {
    return unionRyN;
}

public void setUnionRyN(String unioRyN) {
    this.unionRyN = unioRyN;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ObjetoArchivos [miRuta=" + miRuta + ", miNombre=" + miNombre + ", miTexto=" + miTexto + "]";
}
```

}[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NOTA: Estoy recibiendo un NullPointerException.

IMAGENES DE APORTE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas colocando demasiado codigo e imagenes, para luego decir que tiene un `NullPointerException, que es igual a algun objeto vacio` si te fijas en la ultima imagen te dice claramente que el error se esta produciendo en el archivo `ControladorArchivos.java` en la linea **83** y subio hasta la linea **118**, a partir de eso, entonces solo debes de colocar esos fragmentos de codigo en tu pregunta. Ya es hora de ir aprendiendo a leer el StackTrace de las excepciones.

Comment: Se que el error viene de hay brother, pero nose porque si estoy llenando los campos correctamante osea no vienen vacios los campos

Comment: y cual es la linea 118 del archivo ControladorArchivos.java

Comment: modeloArchivo.CreaArchivo(objetoArchivo); esta parte men

Comment: en que momento instancias `modeloArchivo` verifica que no este nulo.

Comment: wow bro genio, eso era

Comment: Grande bro, una simple instancia que se me paso jajaj bien

Comment: No te asombre si tu preguna es eliminada, ya que la pueden considerar como un error tipografico.

Comment: Si mala mia, Gracias bro. todo por una simple instancia